# How to detect window width changes without resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I already looked for the `.resize()` jquery function but the jquery `.resize()` only triggers when the window is being resized, what i wanted was a trigger that shoots when the width changes for example, instead of changing the browser width the user clicks in the button to maximize and the function fails to trigger, i have a function that fires a function on `resize()`, is there any function that is like `on("windowwidthchanges")` ?

Comment: Is your button click throwing an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can detect both events and just execute code when it's a width change:

```
var width = $(window).width();
$(window).resize(function(){
   if($(this).width() != width){
      width = $(this).width();
       console.log(width);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've checked Chrome, Firefox and IE11. All 3 browsers trigger the alert when the maximize button is clicked.

```
$(window).resize(function(){ alert("resized"); });
```

What, specifically, are you trying to do that this doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can move the code to a named function and call it on resize and when clicking the button.

Or, you can trigger the resize when clicking the button:

```
$("button").on("click", function(){
   $(window).trigger("resize");
});
```

Examples: http://jsfiddle.net/cde7fwrb/

EDIT: I see you were talking about the browser maximise button. Oh well....